# Using machinist instead of fixtures

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, fixtures, machinist

In my **Rails 3** application, I have a *User* model with the following fields

```
   name: string
   email: string
   children: has_many association to another model
```

I'm using [machinist 2](https://github.com/notahat/machinist) to generate mock data, its *blueprint* looks like

```
User.blueprint do
   name { 'user{sn}' }
   email { '{object.name}@domain.com' }
end
```

And User's *Unit Test*:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  should have_many( :children )
  should validate_uniqueness_of( :email )
  should_not allow_value("blah").for(:email)
  should_not allow_value("b lah").for(:email)
  should allow_value("a@b.com").for(:email)
  should allow_value("asdf@asdf.com").for(:email)
end
```

When I generated the user model, it created a fixture file. My understanding is that when I run `rake`, Rails uses that fixture file to generate objects used in the tests. Which is not what I want. **I want Rails to use machinist's blueprints** just a seamlessly as it uses the fixtures file.

Is there a way to do this? Is there some way to tell rails that it needs to use blueprints instead of fixtures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to config/application.rb:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.fixture_replacement :machinist
end
```

You can safely trash the old fixtures folder too, unless you want to keep them obviously!